# Faulty Numlock in External Numpad

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, configuration, peripherals

I have purchased an A4Tech Mini Numpad. It works fine on Windows, and is just out of the box.

Unfortunately, in my Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (HP Notebook), the numlock seems to turn itself off after a few clicks.

Test Examples:

- Intended input: <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>
- What happens: <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>Home</kbd>
  <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>
- (Numlock shows on)

Then

- (After auto-triggered numlock. Numlock shows on)
- Intended input: <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>Numlock</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>
- What happens: <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Numlock</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>
- (Numlock shows off)

Then

- (Numlock shows off)
- Intended Input: <kbd>Numlock</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>
- What happens: <kbd>Numlock</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>
- (Numlock shows on)

Using `$ showkey`
This is the output of 5 presses of numpad 7

```
...
7keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
keycode  71 press
keycode  71 release
keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
7keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
keycode  71 press
keycode  71 release
keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
^[[1~keycode  71 press
keycode  71 release
^[[1~keycode  71 press
keycode  71 release
^[[1~keycode  71 press
keycode  71 release
```

This is the output of 5 presses of numpad 3

```
...
3keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
keycode  81 press
keycode  81 release
keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
3keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
keycode  81 press
keycode  81 release
keycode  69 press
keycode  69 release
^[[6~keycode  81 press
keycode  81 release
^[[6~keycode  81 press
keycode  81 release
^[[6~keycode  81 press
keycode  81 release
```

My HP Notebook has no included Numpad, and that's probably why it defaults to Numlock off.

So, is there a way for me to maybe give it a driver, or change the default to Numlock on?

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing `numlockx`.

```
$ apt install numlockx
```

In [Ask Ubuntu General Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201), user [**dessert**](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051) [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50385037#50385037) me these 2 similar questions. They aren't the same problem but installing `numlockx` from their answers stopped it for now. If ever it seems to stop working, just send `$ numlockx` in the terminal to have it restart.

- [How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/155679/147428)
- [How do I make my system keep the numlock turned on at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/q/796929/147428)

Added info: Context clues from Google searches imply that Ubuntu has a GENERAL problem with numlocks, and assumes you don't need to have it automatically fixed. `numlockx` seems to be Ubuntu's workaround driver for it, and is referenced in this [FAQ about Numlocks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock).