# Why does NumLock LED not shine while NumLock mode is on?

Tags: numlock

I often notice that the NumLock LED is off although NumLock mode is on actually and the numeric keypad works as it is meant to when NumLock is on. Pressing NumLock twice (to turn it off and on again) lights the LED up. The effect only takes place on Ubuntu (16.04), it doesn't take place when running Windows XP, Windows 7 or Xubuntu (15.10) on the same machine.

This is tolerable but a little bit annoying and I'd like to fix this if possible. Does anybody here happen to know the reason behind this quirk and ways to cure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known little bug -> [Num LED state does not correspond with actual state after boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dconf/+bug/1520237).
It happens when starting to type too early after booting the computer.
It also happens when opening an application with root privileges too early. If you wait about one or two minutes, it works flawlessly. As it is one of them 'not so important' bugs ... it still seems to be not solved.
You may want to confirm the bug on launchpad to increase the importance. You may want to check out this answer as well -> [Num-Lock LED state does not correspond with internal state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628115/num-lock-led-state-does-not-correspond-with-internal-state-after-boot-15-04-15/702791#702791).

Comment: `It happens when starting to type too early after booting the computer. It also happens when opening an application with root privileges too early. If you wait about one or two minutes, it works flawlessly` - not really. My computer always has a minute or two between I boot it up and log in. The problem also happens often while I am using the computer, long after I turn it on and even [some time] after I fix the glitch by pressing the NumLock button twice. Needless to say I don't run programs with root privileges every day as well.

Comment: +1 Confirmed and subscribed and added a link from [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/820421/225694) where I remembered mentioning this issue. Hopefully we can drive more traffic to [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dconf/+bug/1520237) and this will eventually be fixed. :-)