# Why are the keyboard indicator lights out of sync in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, indicator

As I noted in my answer to [How do I make the Caps Lock key a third Shift key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82837/how-do-i-make-the-caps-lock-key-a-third-shift-key) The keyboard indicator lights seem to go out of sync at boot on Ubuntu 16.04 For example Set your BIOS to Num Lock ON and boot. Keep an eye on the indicator throughout the boot and login process. You'll note that it goes out and has to be tapped twice before it accurately reflects the num lock status. Why is this and how can this faulty behavior be resolved.

One of the systems I'm experiencing this on doesn't have an option to turn off the numlock at boot. The other one does and even when NumLock on at boot is disabled the indicator light is still out of sync.

Comment: What happens when you set BIOS to Num Lock OFF and boot?

Comment: Must confess I've never notice Num Lock key problems but there is a a whole bunch described here: [ubuntu.com/community/NumLock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock)

Comment: FTR I have numbers in my password and use the numeric keypad without every hitting the numlock key so never noticed any problems. Both my latptop and wireless keyboard have PS/2 style 104 keyboard layout with separate numeric keypad if that helps.

Comment: Oopsie, there is no light on my numlock or scroll lock keys only my Capslock key. *blush*

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well that certainly avoids confusion....

Comment: I have had experience with group of dumb Wyse terminals with USB keyboards and one of them had the numlock indicator light reverse of actual state. It drove me batty. But it wasn't the VM software because other machines in group worked properly. So although unable to help, I personally understand your frustration :)