# A new use for Lenovo onekey recovery key

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, ubuntu-gnome

I have a Lenovo G570 laptop with a little key called onekey recovery next to the power button, and since coming to Linux it has became useless.

Is there a way to make this key into a reset button for example? Or to add an entry in Grub to make it load recovery options?

I've seen similar posts in here but I don't have windows or a dual boot, my disk is a single disk partition with Ubuntu Gnome installed, I don't even have SWAP space.

Comment: From what I can tell, after boot, the OneKey key becomes another keyboard key. Hold on, I figured out the scancode a few weeks ago.

Comment: What model of Lenovo laptop do you have? I have a  Lenovo Ideapad Z510, and I run Ubuntu on it, and the OneKey works as a way to boot into a BIOS menu (I think it goes to boot devices first). You might want to confirm this functionality, as I use it pretty regularly when booting into different media.

Comment: @richbl It's a G570, and no it doesn't do anything, it would boot the computer if off, but when it's running, nothing at all.

Comment: @Muaad See my updated answer. I think it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have an idea how to use this button with GRUB, but there are at least two approaches how to make it usable within Ubuntu. For example if you want to bind the reboot command to that button you could: (1) create **acpi event** or (2) create **custom shortcut**.

---

### Create `acpi event` and bind the reboot command to it

First you need to use `acpi_listen` and catch the event when the button is pressed. Just execute the command `acpi_listen` and press the button:

```bsh
$ acpi_listen 
button/prog1 PROG1 00000080 00000000 K
```

- In the above example `button/prog1 PROG1 00000080 00000000 K` is the event on my system when I press the discussed button.

Then you should crate a file that will handle this event. The file must be located in the directory `/etc/acpi/events/`. Call it for example `reboot`. The content of `/etc/acpi/events/reboot` should be similar as:

```bsh
# /etc/acpi/events/reboot
# This will reboot the system
event=button/prog1 PROG1 00000080 00000000 K
action=systemctl reboot
```

Save the file and restart the acpi daemon:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart acpid.service
```

IMO this is the most simple method. This should work also when the user is not logged in. Here are few references where you can find additional information and examples:

- [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980997/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-when-the-lid-is-twisted-or-closed/980999#980999)
- [Ubuntu 17.10 laptop doesn't suspend on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983168/ubuntu-17-10-laptop-doesnt-suspend-on-lid-close/985711#985711)
- [Battery drains down even after shut down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974573/battery-drains-down-even-after-shut-down/975574#975574)

---

### Create `acpi event` and bind a script to it

We can add an insurance in case you press the button accidentally. Here we will create a script that will use a `tmp` file as flag and counter as it is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001081/566421). Thus the system reboot will be performed when you press the button three times.

1. Modify `/etc/acpi/events/reboot` in this way:

   ```bsh
   # /etc/acpi/events/reboot
   # This will reboot the system
   event=button/prog1 PROG1 00000080 00000000 K
   action=/etc/acpi/reboot.sh
   ```

   Restart the acpi daemon:

   ```bsh
   sudo systemctl restart acpid.service
   ```
2. Create the script `/etc/acpi/reboot.sh` and put the following lines as its content:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash  
   FLAG_FILE="/tmp/sysyem_reboot_flag"

   # If the file exists and it is older than 30 seconds, then reset the counter 
   # Else If the file doesn't exist or its 'value' is less than 2, then increment
   # Else (when the file exists, its value is equal or greater than 2, and its age is less than 30 seconds) reboot the system 

   if [ -f "${FLAG_FILE}" ] && [[ $(find "${FLAG_FILE}" -newermt '-30 sec') == '' ]]; then
       echo '1' > "$FLAG_FILE"
   elif [ ! -f "${FLAG_FILE}" ] || (( $(cat "$FLAG_FILE") < 2 )); then
       touch "$FLAG_FILE"
       NEW_VALUE=$(( $(cat "$FLAG_FILE") + 1)) && echo "$NEW_VALUE" > "$FLAG_FILE"
   else
       systemctl reboot
   fi
   ```

   Make it executable:

   ```bsh
   sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/reboot.sh
   ```

Now the `systemctl reboot` command will be performed when you press the button three times, within 30 secconds.

---

### Create `custom shortcut` and bind a script to it

1. Crate a script `/usr/local/bin/my_rbt` (it could be named and located whenever you want) and make it executable. Here is a single command line that does that:

   ```bsh
   $ echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nsudo systemctl reboot' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/my_rbt && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my_rbt
   #!/bin/sh
   systemctl reboot
   ```
2. The problem is (within this approach) we must use `sudo` to execute the script and should allow the users to do that without password - here are provided more details about this step: [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009) So we must crate a file located in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, called for example `my_rbt`. For this purposes we should use the command `visudo -f`:

   ```bsh
   sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_rbt
   ```

   The content of the file should be:

   ```bsh
   ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/my_rbt
   ```
3. Go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** (tab) → **Custom Shortcuts** (section) → Add new <kbd>+</kbd>.

   [image]

   - In the *Custom shortcut* window type:
   - *Name*: `reboot`
   - *Command*: `sudo /usr/local/bin/my_rbt`
   - Click on *<kbd>Apply</kbd>*
4. Click on `Disabled` in the right column and press the discussed button.

   [image]

That's it.

Comment: The first solution worked like a charm, I will award you the bounty as soon as the system allows me to. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to help, @MuaadElSharif. I've updated the answer with an additional elaboration of the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that for Lenovo laptops (at least my G575) the OneKey Recovery key is another key.

Using the `xev` command, you can find out the scancode. `xev` will open a window with a black square, move your mouse inside it and then press the OKR key.

```
KeyPress event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x497, subw 0x1600002, time 1092364, (50,41), root:(52,479),
    state 0x0, keycode 156 (keysym 0x1008ff41, XF86Launch1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x497, subw 0x1600002, time 1092364, (50,41), root:(52,479),
    state 0x0, keycode 156 (keysym 0x1008ff41, XF86Launch1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You can see the keycode as `keycode` **`156`**.

After finding the keycode, all you need to look up is how to map a keycode to a specific action. Here's some helpful questions:

- [How do I make the Caps Lock key a third Shift key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82837/how-do-i-make-the-caps-lock-key-a-third-shift-key)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb

Comment: could you add how to do that?

Comment: @Mark thanks for showing me the way to display keys, and I'd appreciate if you show me how to do it, I asked because I don't know.

Comment: @Muaad I'm sorry, but I can't seem to find any references on how to do that, and to be honest I never bothered to map the keys, I only know it is possible. Previous versions of Ubuntu (before 13.04) used the `xmodmap` command, but as of 13.04, they use `xkb` instead. I've asked [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/906802/595510) about how to use `xkb`.

Comment: @Muaad Please see my updated answer.