# WHy CAps lock is too slow to turn off in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does turning Caps Lock off take such a long time to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58080/why-does-turning-caps-lock-off-take-such-a-long-time-to-work)

> **TH**is is a strange problem. **NO**tice how the beginning of my sentences include two capitals? Well, over the years I have developed
>   a terrible habit... and it may be too late to fix. Instead of holding
>   shift like a normal person to capitalize my works, I hit Caps Lock,
>   then hit the letter, then hit Caps Lock again. PRetty weird huh? I
>   Took an official government typing test recently and scored 99 words a
>   minute, so it hasn't been a huge hindrance until now that I use
>   Ubuntu. IN Ubuntu, often when I do my crazy method of typing, the Caps
>   LOck won't turn off fast enough. IT's not my keyboard. I didn't have
>   this problem in WIndows. IT's extremely annoying. Is there a cure for
>   this?

Took the question from [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11690093) because it's just explaining the same problem I am having here.